# Use of pasting operator `##` with types in C

Tags: c, macros, typeof

Is it possible to define a macro for the C preprocessor which takes an array as argument and expands to `<type of array elements>_string`? For example if `x` in an array of integers the macro invoked with argument `x` should expand to `int_string`.

I tried with

```
#define TypePaste(array) typeof(array[0])##_string
```

but it expands to `)_string`.

Even using multiple levels of indirection for the `##` operand the macro doesn't expand correctly.

Comment: Imagine preprocessor directives as a dumb mechanism that gets its turn prior to compiling, for string manipulation, where the strings are lines of your code.

Comment: There are ways, but it kind of depends on if you wish the macro to create a new type, a new variable name, or refer to an existing type or variable.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an xy problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ludin the macro should expand to the name of an existing function. I'd like to define a function `<type>_string` for every existing type and then use the macro to select the right function according to the type of the array given.

Comment: @JensGustedt I'd like to define a generic function to sort arrays to which I don't need to pass the array type as an argument.

Comment: @OscarCharles Look at `qsort()` for what such a function looks like in C.

Comment: @FUZxxl I did, and indeed I was asking if passing the comparison function is necessary or can be made automatic with some compiler directives. I just did this with the size of the array elements, so maybe the same can be done for the comparison function.

Comment: C11 introduced the `_Generic` keyword, but few compilers support it as far as I know.

Comment: Can you write an algorithm that describes the comparison function for all possible cases?

Comment: @FUZxxl Not yet, but in the worst case I'll have to define a function for any type, which isn't too bad, considered that I should do it only once.

Comment: @OscarCharles Point is, there are different valid comparison functions for each type (e.g. sort in reverse order), so you have to specify a comparison function anyway.

Comment: @MOehm, the newer versions of gcc and clang both implement `_Generic`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. _Generic seems to do the trick, although it's not standard C so I'd rather not use it, if i can. I found another way, but requires an "hidden" variable allocated when the array is initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not all that clear what problem you are trying to solve, but given your comment:

> the macro should expand to the name of an existing function. I'd like to define a function `<type>_string` for every existing type and then use the macro to select the right function according to the type of the array given.

Then you could use the C11 `_Generic` keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void int_string (size_t size, int array[size])
{
  printf("I am %s, do stuff here.\n", __func__);
}

void float_string (size_t size, float array[size])
{
  printf("I am %s, do stuff here.\n", __func__);
}

#define TypePaste(array)          \ 
  _Generic( array,                \
            int:   int_string,    \
            float: float_string ) \
  (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array), array) // function parameters



int main()
{
  int   i_arr[5];
  float f_arr[3];

  TypePaste(i_arr);
  TypePaste(f_arr);
}
```

Output:

```
I am int_string, do stuff here.
I am float_string, do stuff here.
```

Note: this assumes that the passed parameter is a local/file scope allocated array. If passing a pointer, there's no type safety and the program will fail.

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible. At the *translation phase* (the preprocessing phase) where macros are expanded and tokens are concatenated, the compiler (at this point, the preprocessor) does not yet have the notion of a *type* and thus cannot possibly generate types.

Comment: Preprocessing is one of several numbered translation phases, specifically phase 4 (C11 §5.1.1.2).

Comment: So there's no way to make the compiler evaluate `typeof()` first, or to somehow paste the strings after `typeof()` has been expanded?

Comment: @OscarCharles No, there isn't. If you want to do something like that, you have to write a custom code generator. If you ask the problem you are trying to solve by doing that, maybe we can find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

C11's `_Generic` type selection is the "proper" way to do what you want. There are other, platform dependent solutions, tough.

If you are using gcc – you don't say so eplicitly, but you use gcc's extension `typeof` already – you can use gcc's [statement expresions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) and [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) to create a comparison function for `qsort` on the spot:

```
double a[5] = {8.4, 8.1, 9.3, 12.2, 5.2};

qsort(a, 5, sizeof(*a), ({
    int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
        const typeof(a[0]) *pp = p;
        const typeof(a[0]) *qq = q;

        return (*pp < *qq) ? -1 : (*pp > *qq);
    }
    cmp;
}));
```

This creates a function and returns its address. (The last statement of a compound expression is its value. The scope of the local variables is the statement expression, but a nested function is not created on the stack so its safe to return a pointer to that function.)

For primitive types, where you want to sort according to the comparison operators `<`  and `>`, you can turn that into a macro:

```
#define COMPARE(ARRAY)({             \
        int cmp(const void *p, const void *q) {         \
            const typeof(ARRAY[0]) *pp = p;             \
            const typeof(ARRAY[0]) *qq = q;             \
            return (*pp < *qq) ? -1 : (*pp > *qq);      \
        }                                               \
        cmp;                                            \
    })

qsort(a, 5, sizeof(*a), COMPARE(a));
```

or even:

```
#define SORT(ARRAY, N)                                  \
    qsort(ARRAY, N, sizeof(*ARRAY), COMPARE(ARRAY))

SORT(a, 5);
```

That's not Standard C, so if you need compatibility between platforms, this is out of the question.